# Finding the highest and lowest number of lowercase words

Tags: java

I think I'm close but I'm stuck currently. 
basically what I need to do is ask for 3 strings and find the lower number of lowercase and the highest number of the lower case from the input

```
import java.util.*;

public class Practice_program1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int z = 0;
        String user;
        String a = input.nextLine();
        String b = input.nextLine();
        String c = input.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a String: ");
            user = input.nextLine();

            if (Character.isLowerCase(a.charAt(i)))
                x++;
            else if (Character.isLowerCase(b.charAt(i)))
                y++;
            else if (Character.isLowerCase(c.charAt(i)))
                z++;

            {
                if (x > y && x > z)
                    ;
                System.out.print(user + " has the highest number of lowercase letters" + a);
                if (y > z && y < x)
                    ;
                System.out.print(user + " has the lowerst number of lowercase letters" + b);

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: remove `;` after `if`

Comment: *lower number of lowercase and the highest number of the lower case* not sure what you are asking ? Could you post sample input and output as well ?

Comment: Ahh that would be useful if i posted the question. It's not giving me an output that what the issue is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are a few things I want to point out before providing the solution.

1. I did not understand the use of the String variable "user". Hence, I skipped it. If you can explain its usage, I can edit the code accordingly, if required.
2. The condition of two strings having the same number of lowercase letters is not being considered.
3. The other thing is that you are trying to count the number of lower case letters using the iteration variable i but what if the strings are of three different lengths?

That is why I thought it would be better to write a separate method to count the number of lower case letters in each string and then I am comparing their count to find the string with the maximum lowercase letters and the minimum lowercase letters.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String user;
    String a = input.nextLine();
    String b = input.nextLine();
    String c = input.nextLine();
    input.close();

    int countOfA = findLowerCaseNumber(a);
    int countOfB = findLowerCaseNumber(b);
    int countOfC = findLowerCaseNumber(c);

    if(countOfA > countOfB && countOfA > countOfC){
        System.out.println(a + " has the highest number of lowercase letters " + countOfA );
        if(countOfB < countOfC)
            System.out.println(b + " has the lowest number of lowercase letters " + countOfB );
        else
            System.out.println(c + " has the lowest number of lowercase letters " + countOfC );
    }
    else if(countOfB > countOfA && countOfB > countOfC){
        System.out.println(b + " has the highest number of lowercase letters " + countOfB );
        if(countOfA < countOfC)
            System.out.println(a + " has the lowest number of lowercase letters " + countOfA );
        else
            System.out.println(c + " has the lowest number of lowercase letters " + countOfC );
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(c + " has the highest number of lowercase letters " + countOfC );
        if(countOfB < countOfC)
            System.out.println(b + " has the lowest number of lowercase letters " + countOfB );
        else
            System.out.println(a + " has the lowest number of lowercase letters " + countOfA );
    }
}

public static int findLowerCaseNumber(String str){
    int lowerCaseLetters = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        // I prefer to use the ASCII values of lower case letters but what you have used is also correct.
        if(str.charAt(i) > 96 && str.charAt(i) < 123)
            lowerCaseLetters++;
    return lowerCaseLetters;
}
```

Instead of manually comparing the count of each string, you can also use the Math.max() and Math.min() as mentioned by nullpointer to derive the solution.

Comment: OKay i realize it was very unclear. But basically the output should be as:         "the input" has the maximum number of lower case letters of: "3" or however much the input is                                                                                 "the input" has the minimum number of lowercase letters of: "1"

Comment: I really appreciate the help. What I was doing wrong was that I was trying to do them all together not separately.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code executes as follows:

```
if (x > y && x > z); // no statement executed even if the condition is satified
System.out.print(user + " has the highest number of lowercase letters" + a); // would print to console no matter x,y,z is max of min
if (y > z && y < x); // same as  above
System.out.print(user + " has the lowerst number of lowercase letters" + b); // same as above
```

---

Also to find out the max you can make use of [`Math.max(int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max(int,%20int)) as:

```
Math.max(x, Math.max(y,z)); // this would return the max out of three
```

Similarly, you can try to find out the minimum as well and then print them.

```
System.out.print(user + " has the lowest number of lowercase letters" + Math.min(x, Math.min(y,z)));
```

Comment: oh ok I will use Math.max() and get back to you thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your task caused me a few questions:
1. The loop `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)` says that you count only first 3 chars of input strings - `a`, `b` and `c`. And you print result every iteration. Are such conditions of the problem?
2. You read `user` three times. Is it normal?

Anyway, there is the way of a counting of lower case characters by streams:

```
private static long getLowerCaseCount(String str) {
    return str.chars().map(i -> (char)i).filter(Character::isLowerCase).count();
}
```

Using:

```
long x = getLowerCaseCount(a);
long y = getLowerCaseCount(b);
long z = getLowerCaseCount(c);
long min = Math.min(x, Math.min(y, z));
long max = Math.max(x, Math.max(y, z));
```

Comment: Oh no, it is not I see what you mean. What i needed was to ask the user to input 3 times. That i taught was going to be something like. "THE INPUT" "has the maximum number of lower case of:" "3"